# mysql - replace &#39; with single quote in a field

Tags: mysql, replace

I'm not exactly sure what happened because I migrated from One server to another of the same spec and SQL...

Still in comments and titles the new database shows the characters `&#39;` instead of `'`
and I was wondering if I could ask for help in either replacing `&#39;` with `'`
or if it was simpler just deleting `&#39;`

Thanks so much...
Steff

Comment: This doesn't make much sense yet. Please add much, much more detail about what the problem is

Comment: One more time, but don't assume we're telepathic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use MySQL's `REPLACE` method (look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)):

**UPDATE**
Changed the statement to reflect the OP's naming:

```
UPDATE database1.vb_ppgal_albums
   SET pp_photos = REPLACE(pp_photos, '&#39;', '\'')
```

Good luck.

Comment: Sorry guys... I should have put more detail in the question.

Comment: What I have is what looks like rubbish added to the content of a field. So in the Database: database1> table: vb_ppgal_albums field: pp_photos  I was expecting to see the content something like this 
Marazion's view 
but instead the content is this 
Marazion&#39;s view
For some strange reason &#39; has been added to content of the pp_photos so I would like to remove the &#39; and leave the rest of the text in the pp_photos field intact.

Comment: Err, that's what the SQL statemant does. I've updated the statement to meat your naming.

Answer (score -1):

The following is the coding that I use to update double-quote in MySQL.  I use the `REPLACE` function.  The first parameter is the field_name that I want to have searched, the second is the escaping of the double quote (\") as the search string, followed by escaping of the escape character (\) followed by the double quote, which will insert into the field name (\"). In the table I will now have a measurement of '1/2\"' instead of '1/2"', which was my goal.  I hope this helps. (PS, the Where clause is for show, you may not need it.)

```
UPDATE `table_name` 
SET 
`field_name` = REPLACE(`field_name`, '\"', '\\"')
WHERE `Id` > 125
```